# Get Image Having the ID

Tags: plugins, images, shortcode, id

My problem is the following:
I have a plugin that let people register and upload pictures but... it saves them in a metadata that can t be outputted directly with the short-codes in the plugin.

The fact is, the metadata points to the ID of the image. what I need is to understand how to create a short-code that takes an ID of a picture and gives as an output the image.

I'm sure its very simple but while I have some experience in making sites on WP I m really bad with the php.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below code in your `functions.php` and then you can use this `[get_image_by_id id="your-image-id"]` shortcode to get the image

```
add_shortcode( 'get_image_by_id', 'the_dramatist_get_image_by_id');

function the_dramatist_get_image_by_id($atts) {
    return wp_get_attachment_image($atts['id']);
}
```

Here `"your-image-id"` is numeric ID of the image.

Hope that helps.